# Stop col from displaying under certain resolutions

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following code (fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Wy22s/470/)) which is fine for displaying a header.

```
<!--Header-->
<div id="header-content-wrapper">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div id="header" class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2 panel">
                <img class="logo" width="210" height="60" src="https://www.google.ie/images/srpr/logo11w.png">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-7 panel">
                <div class="text"><span>A piece of text here</span></div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3  panel header-right">
                <form action="/account/LogOff" class="navbar-right" id="logoutForm" method="post">
                    <input type="hidden"><span>Welcome, Person!</span>
                    <span><a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()">Log off</a></span>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I would like the "piece of text" and "welcome person", to disappear instead of wrapping or stacking when the resolution gets too small (extra small). I have tried `hidden-xs` but it doesn't seem to have the effect I am looking for.

Any ideas would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're hiding a column for sm, I would make your other two columns (logo and logout) equal say col-sm-6?

Also a heads up your logo width is too big for the column. See the [Bootstrap docs](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#images) on the class 'img-responsive' or make the column that contains the logo col-md-3, and the column containing "A peice of text here" col-md-6.

```
 <!--Header-->
<div id="header-content-wrapper">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div id="header" class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-2 panel">
                <img class="logo" width="210" height="60" src="https://www.google.ie/images/srpr/logo11w.png">
            </div>
            <div class="hidden-sm col-md-7 panel">
                <div class="text"><span>A piece of text here</span></div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3  panel header-right">
                <form action="/account/LogOff" class="navbar-right" id="logoutForm" method="post">
                    <input type="hidden"><span>Welcome, Person!</span>
                    <span><a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()">Log off</a></span>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**jsfiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/Wy22s/471/embedded/result/

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply! I just realised I made a mistake in my post. I should have said I wanted the, "piece of text" *and* the "Welcome, Person!" to disappear when the view port is small (or perhaps extra small)

Comment: See this jsfiddle instead, it will hide the text and welcome on extra small devices: http://jsfiddle.net/Wy22s/476/embedded/result/

Code: http://jsfiddle.net/Wy22s/476/

If you wanted to update this to hide for small devices too, you add hidden-sm next to where there are hidden-xs. E.g <div class="hidden-xs hidden-sm col-sm-4"> etc

Answer (score 0):

I have almost got the effect I want using `@media`:

```
<!--Header-->
<div id="header-content-wrapper">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div id="header" class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2 panel">
                <img class="logo" width="210" height="60" src="https://www.google.ie/images/srpr/logo11w.png">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-7 panel">
                <div class="text" id="text"><span>A piece of text here</span></div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3  panel header-right">
                <form action="/account/LogOff" class="navbar-right" id="logoutForm" method="post">
                    <input type="hidden"><span>Welcome, Person!</span>
                    <span><a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()">Log off</a></span>
                </form>
            </div>
```

css

```
.header-right {
    color: #333e48;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: italic;
    line-height: 60px;
    padding-right: 20px;
}

.text {
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #97979d;
    line-height: 60px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-left: 20px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 546px) {
    #text {
        display: none
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 750px) {
    #logoutForm {
        display: none
    }
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Wy22s/477/embedded/result/)